# How to slice 2D array from 3D array using a 2D array that represents the indices for the first dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Create a sample 3D array with shape (10, 33, 66)

`data_3d = np.random.random((10, 33, 66))`

Create a 2D index array with shape (33, 66) representing indices for the first dimension

`index_2d = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(33, 66))`

How to slice a 2D array with shape (33,66) from the 3D array based on the index array?

Comment: It's not clear which indices you're looking to get from the 3D array. How do you interpret the meaning of the values in `index_2d`? For example, if `index_2d[1,5] = 3`, which index do you want from `data_3d`? Is it `data_3d[3, 1, 5]`?

Comment: Hi Jared, your interpretation is correct. When index_2d[1,5] = 3, I am looking for the value of data_3d[3, 1, 5]

Comment: With the newish `take_along_axis`, `res=np.take_along_axis(data_3d, index_2d[None], axis=0)`

Comment: Or 'old-fashioned' indexing: `res1=data_3d[index_2d, np.arange(33)[:,None], np.arange(66)]`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [`np.choose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) function.

```py
chosen = np.choose(index_2d, data_3d)
```